# Is it possible to convert Cartesian equation to polar or parametric equation?

Tags: polar-coordinates, parametric

I was reading Wikipedia to find interesting curves to be plotted using a polar coordinate system. And I've found an interesting shape, which is [Squircle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squircle):

[image: Illustration of Squircle that looks like rounded square]

Wikipedia shows this equation:

$$ {\vert \frac{x - a}{r_a} \vert}^n + {\vert \frac{y - b}{r_b} \vert}^n = 1 $$

Can this equation be converted to a [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) equation or [parametric equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation)?

I'm asking because I want to write code that will plot the shape and I have no idea how to do that if I have an equation that has both x and y in it, it would be silly to iterate over every pixel on the screen to draw a shape that looks like something that should have polar or parametric representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For parametric equations, relationship $\cos^2 a + \sin^2 a= 1$ invites to set:

$$\begin{cases}\frac{x-a}{r_a}&=&(\cos t)^{2/n}\\ \frac{y-b}{r_b}&=&(\sin t)^{2/n}\end{cases}$$

giving:

$$\begin{cases}x(t)&=&r_a \cos(t)^{2/n} + a\\ y(t)&=&r_b \sin(t)^{2/n}+b \end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I need for this particular case, but can you explain a bit more what are the steps to convert this type of equation to a parametric equation? I don't understand from where the first formula came from, and how it's related to the 2nd pair of equations.

Comment: If for the first group of equations, I take the power n of both, the 2 RHS become $\left((something)^{\frac{2}n}\right)^n = (something)^2$. Now add the two equations.

Comment: The transition say from the first equ. of the first pair of equations to the first equation of the second pair : $\frac{p-q}{r}=s \iff p-q=rs \iff p=q+rs$